# Where can I find the list of changes to the Catechism of the Catholic Church since the 1997 second edition?

Tags: resource-request, catholic-catechism

Besides the change to CCC 2267 [approved by Pope Francis on Aug 2, 2018](https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2018/08/02/180802a.html), where can I find other updates to the Catechism since the 1997 Second Edition ([published in 2000 with Glossary and Index, ISBN 1574551108](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1574551108))?

The [copyright page](https://www.usccb.org/sites/default/files/flipbooks/catechism/VI/) of the edition made available by USCCB ([Nov 2019 printing, ISBN 1601376499](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1601376499)) implies that there are other changes:

> In 2016, the *Catechism of the Catholic Church, Second Edition*, was updated to reflect the 2011 English translation of Eucharistic Prayers, Creeds, and other texts in the *Roman Missal, Third Edition*.

I'm hoping to find an official list of precise wording changes such as [this document](https://scborromeo2.org/documents/2020/4/Catechism%20of%20the%20Catholic%20Church%20Edito%20Typica.pdf) which contains a list of modifications between the 1994/1995 edition and the 1997 edition, to facilitate detection whether I'm dealing with an older snippets from the Catechism when browsing the Internet.